# what will be better to use apache kafka or activemq?

Tags: apache-kafka, activemq-classic

## Problem statement:

We will receive a requests to process the item belongs to any Groups given below -

1. Grp1 -> A1,B1,C1,D1,E1
2. Grp2 -> A2,B2,C2,D2,E2
3. Grp3 -> A3,B3,C3,D3,E3

### Scenario 1:

We receive 3 request for A1, B1, C1.
As all the request belongs to same group they should be processed sequentially
(current request should be completed before next request can be picked up for processing)

### Scenario 2:

We receive 4 request for A1, A2, B2, B3
Here request A2 and B2 belongs to same group so they should be processed sequentially as mentioned in Scenario 1
and requests A1 and B3 should be processed in parallel as they belongs to different groups

So basically requests from different groups should be processed in parallel.
and requests from same group should be processed in sequentially manner.

### Current approach :

We are planning to do this with Apache Kafka or activemq as follows-

- Create a topic
- Divide the topic into partitions , One partition will be assigned to every
  group ,so number of partitions will be equals to number of groups
- Each request that belongs to particular group will be sent to the partition
  that is assigned to that group.
- Each partition will have a dedicated consumer which will process requests
  only from that partition.

### Questions :

1. Which one will best suited for the requirement Apache Kafka or activemq ?
2. Any other better approach to solve the same problem ?

Note : The given application can be distributed microservice application with multiple instances running.

Comment: Note: recommendation questions are considered off topic for Stackoverflow see [help]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know ActiveMQ, but what you described is basically how Kafka works. All produced events in a partition are ordered and are processed in that sequence, and within a consumer group, you can only have one consumer per partition

The only part you'll need to implement is the `Partitioner` interface to guarantee your group to partition logic. Otherwise, the default partitioner wouldn't guarantee X1 and Y2 end up part of the same partition

Comment: Thank you for the response!! Do you think , apart from Queues any other approach could be used to solve the problem ?